# Trouble with Post's Completeness Criterion

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I read this set of notes regarding proving that a set of boolean functions are universal, i.e. that any boolean function can be written with those in the set:

http://cs.ucsb.edu/~victor/ta/cs40/posts-criterion.pdf

I am curious about the function $x \circ y = x \lor \neg y$. The truth table is as follows:

```
x y output
0 0  1
0 1  0
1 0  1
1 1  1
```

Plainly, this function satisfies "preserves 1" (when x = 1 and y = 1, the output is 1), so it can't be universal according to Post. However, it appears to be universal, since you can derive NOT and OR as follows (using 0 for false and 1 for true):

$ 0 \circ x = 0 \lor \neg x = \neg x$

$ x \circ (0 \circ y) = x \lor \neg (0 \circ y) = x \lor \neg \neg y = x \lor y$

Since NOT and OR are a universal set, $\circ$ is universal - but it doesn't seem to fit Post's criteria. How is this possible?

Comment: Hmm... Out of curiosity, to anyone reading, what is the rule on boolean-algebra tag vs propositional-logic tag around here? I'm curious as to which one is considered more appropriate here. I would definitely go for the latter myself, but never retagged a question in such a scenario.

Comment: Are you claiming that $\{\circ,0\}$ is universal, or that $\{\circ\}$ is universal?

Comment: @bof: sure, edited. Had a typo when I stated the function, fixed now. Regarding $\{\circ, 0\}$ vs $\{\circ\}$, I think this is where my confusion stems. I am guessing you are saying that if I am using 0 and 1 in my derivations of NOT and OR, then they must also be part of the set I am claiming to be universal? i.e. with the statements I made in my post, I only proved that $\{\circ, 0\}$ is universal, and to prove that $\{\circ\}$ is universal I'd have to not use 0 in my derivations - correct?

Comment: All right, your $x\circ y$ is just $y\to x..$ And of course $\{\to,\ false\}$ is a well-known "universal set," it's the one used by Church's book. What is Post's criterion?

Comment: I think so, but you shouldn't take my word for it. I took a class in logic in a bygone century.

Comment: That would certainly make sense, now that I think about it. If you post your reasoning as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @bof Do you remember the axioms that Church used in his book for the propositional calculus which had $\rightarrow$ and **false** as the primitive connectives?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I don't remember them, but I managed to find my old copy of the book. The axioms are $$[p\supset[q\supset p]]$$ $$[[s\supset[p\supset q]]\supset[[s\supset p]\supset[s\supset q]]]$$ $$[[[p\supset f]\supset f]\supset p]$$The rules of inference are modus ponens and substitution.

Comment: The third axiom  [[[p ⊃ f] ⊃ f] ⊃ p] differs from the first two in a way.  If you consider 4. [p ⊃ [p ⊃ p]], the first axiom is more general then 4.  For any formula of the type [x ⊃ [y ⊃ z]] the first axiom is uniquely the most general tautology of that type, and the second axiom is uniquely the most general tautology of the type [[a ⊃ [b ⊃ c]] ⊃ [[d ⊃ e] ⊃ [f ⊃ g]]].  I've learned that the third axiom is a special case of the more general tautology [[[p ⊃ q] ⊃ f] ⊃ p].

Comment: What I said above is not very well explained.  Suppose we regiment the order of the variables, such that 'p' always appears first, 'q' second', and 'r' third.  Then [p -> [q -> p]] is unique and more general than any other tautology.  [[p -> [q -> r]] -> [[p -> q] -> [p -> r]]] is also that way.  But, [[[p -> q] -> f] -> p] is more general than [[[p -> f] -> f] -> p].  If you apply appropriate definitions, [[[p -> q] -> f] -> p] can yield both [[[p -> f] -> f] -> p] and [[p <-> q] -> [p -> q]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constants $0$ and $1$ should be considered as functions; they should either be included in your universal set or derivable from it. For example, from the set $\{\land,\neg\},$ we get $0=x\land\neg x$ and $1=\neg0.$

Your function $x\circ y$ is equivalent to $y\to x.$ By itself, it is not universal; every function obtainable from $\circ$ by composition has the property of being true when all the variables are true.

It's well known that $\{\circ,0\}$ or equivalently $\{\to,0\}$ is complete. The presentation of propositional logic in Alonzo Church's *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* used $\to$ and $0$ as the primitive connectives.